# Regex forward reference for code matching rule

Tags: regex

I'm trying to improve our code quality warnings. One warning we want is to make sure that we don't use `NSLog()` but instead use `GPLog()`.

I have a rule to catch these:

```
warning_regex 'Use GPLog() instead of NSLog()', /.*NSLog.*(?!GPLog).*/i
```

This does indeed catch all uses of `NSLog()` in regular code.

However, there is one place where `NSLog()` is allowed... in our `GPLog.swift` source, where we wrap the original call to `NSLog()`. That code looks like this:

```
NSLog("%@:%d [%@]: \(message())", file.lastPathComponent, line, function) // GPLog wrapper
```

As you may have noticed we have a negative forward reference in the rule, and at the end of the above code line I've added `// GPLog wrapper`. The result, I thought, would be "match any line with NSLog unless it is followed by GPLog." But it doesn't work. The above line is still matched and a warning is generated.

What am I missing about negative forward references?? Thank you. Pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one: The problem is that your second ".*" can match anything, including "GPLog". So the negative look-ahead has no effect.

Here's a fix for the regex:

```
/.*NSLog(?!.*GPLog).*/
```